# How to retrieve the long query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

May I ask how to get the whole statement query from running session?

I'd like to check its actual execution plan of it and need to complete query, but sometimes it's too long for Management Studio’s monitor or dynamic view.

Any advice would be so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Profiler and run a trace against the related database.

Comment: Thanks @Lmu92, sorry for my late reply.